# XPath - Match optional child elements or empty text

Tags: ruby, xpath

I have the following code which should add an error if there is an orderEvents element and that element has a child node that is not an orderEvent or empty text. The test cases do a better job of showing what I'm after.

The XPATH expression works in all cases except when there is empty space within the `orderEvents` element. See test case **validVendorPaymentFormat7** below. Here's my XPATH expression.

```
"./expectedVendorPaymentTransactions/orderEvents/node()[not(self::orderEvent) or self::text()[normalize-space(.)!='']]"
```

Test Cases:

```
<TestData>
  <TestcaseList>
    <Testcase>
      <rootIdentifier>validVendorPaymentFormat1</rootIdentifier>
      <expectedVendorPaymentTransactions>
        <orderEvents></orderEvents>
      </expectedVendorPaymentTransactions>
    </Testcase>
    <Testcase>
      <rootIdentifier>validVendorPaymentFormat2</rootIdentifier>
    </Testcase>
    <Testcase>
      <rootIdentifier>validVendorPaymentFormat3</rootIdentifier>
      <expectedVendorPaymentTransactions>
      </expectedVendorPaymentTransactions>
    </Testcase>
    <Testcase>
      <rootIdentifier>validVendorPaymentFormat4</rootIdentifier>
      <expectedVendorPaymentTransactions>
        <orderEvents><orderEvent>SOME_EVENT</orderEvent></orderEvents>
      </expectedVendorPaymentTransactions>
    </Testcase>
     <Testcase>
      <rootIdentifier>validVendorPaymentFormat5</rootIdentifier>
      <expectedVendorPaymentTransactions>
        <orderEvents><orderEvent>SOME_EVENT</orderEvent></orderEvents>
      </expectedVendorPaymentTransactions>
    </Testcase>
    <Testcase>
      <rootIdentifier>validVendorPaymentFormat6</rootIdentifier>
      <expectedVendorPaymentTransactions>
        <orderEvents><orderEvent>SOME_EVENT</orderEvent><orderEvent>SOME_EVENT</orderEvent></orderEvents>
      </expectedVendorPaymentTransactions>
    </Testcase>
    <Testcase>
      <rootIdentifier>validVendorPaymentFormat7</rootIdentifier>
      <expectedVendorPaymentTransactions>
        <orderEvents>
          <orderEvent>SOME_EVENT</orderEvent>
        </orderEvents>
      </expectedVendorPaymentTransactions>
    </Testcase>
  </TestcaseList>
</TestData>
```

The failing case is **validVendorPaymentFormat7**

Failure Message:

```
[exec] Failure:
 [exec]   Order vendor payments format contains elements other than orderEvent for validVendorPaymentFormat7 ["\n          ", "\n        "].
 [exec]   <false> is not true.
```

Changing the failing case to:

```
        <Testcase>
          <rootIdentifier>validVendorPaymentFormat7</rootIdentifier>
          <expectedVendorPaymentTransactions>
            <orderEvents><orderEvent>SOME_EVENT</orderEvent></orderEvents>
          </expectedVendorPaymentTransactions>
        </Testcase>
```

Results in a pass.

Unfortunately on http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html test case #7 returns an empty list as expected.

**UPDATE - Adding code**

Ruby Version: 1.9

irb -v = 0.9.6

Test File:

```
require 'rexml/document'

xpath = "//expectedVendorPaymentTransactions/orderEvents/node()[not(self::orderEvent) or self::text()[translate(., ' &#10;', '')!='']]"
document = REXML::Document.new <<EOF 
    <Testcase>
      <rootIdentifier>validVendorPaymentFormat7</rootIdentifier>
      <expectedVendorPaymentTransactions>
        <orderEvents>
          <orderEvent>SOME_EVENT</orderEvent>
        </orderEvents>
      </expectedVendorPaymentTransactions>
    </Testcase>
EOF

document2 = REXML::Document.new <<EOF 
    <Testcase>
      <rootIdentifier>validVendorPaymentFormat7</rootIdentifier>
      <expectedVendorPaymentTransactions>
        <orderEvents><orderEvent>SOME_EVENT</orderEvent></orderEvents>
      </expectedVendorPaymentTransactions>
    </Testcase>
EOF

puts "1: #{REXML::XPath.match(document, xpath).inspect}"
puts "2: #{REXML::XPath.match(document2, xpath).inspect}"
```

Output:

```
irb(main):001:0> load './test/test_rexp.rb'
1: ["\n          ", "\n        "]
2: []
=> true
```

Latest Revision of Jens:

```
irb(main):009:0> load './test/test_rexp.rb'
1: ", "
2: ", "
=> true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropping the whitespace handling from XPATH and using a rather easy ruby workaround works.

Working code:

```
require 'rexml/document'
require 'rexml/text'

xpath = "//expectedVendorPaymentTransactions/orderEvents/node()[not(self::orderEvent)]"
document = REXML::Document.new <<EOF 
    <Testcase>
      <rootIdentifier>validVendorPaymentFormat7</rootIdentifier>
      <expectedVendorPaymentTransactions>
        <orderEvents>
          <orderEvent>Fulfill</orderEvent>
        </orderEvents>
      </expectedVendorPaymentTransactions>
    </Testcase>
EOF

document2 = REXML::Document.new <<EOF 
    <Testcase>
      <rootIdentifier>validVendorPaymentFormat7</rootIdentifier>
      <expectedVendorPaymentTransactions>
        <orderEvents><orderEvent>Fulfill</orderEvent></orderEvents>
      </expectedVendorPaymentTransactions>
    </Testcase>
EOF

elements = REXML::XPath.match(document, xpath)
elements.reject! { |element| 
      element.instance_of?(REXML::Text) and element.value.gsub(/[\n ]/,"") == ''
    }
puts "1: #{elements.inspect}"

elements2 = REXML::XPath.match(document2, xpath)
elements2.reject! { |element| 
      element.instance_of?(REXML::Text) and element.value.gsub(/[\n\t ]/,"") == ''
    }
puts "2: #{elements2.inspect}"
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems Ruby doesn't handle newlines as whitespace in `normalize-space(...)`. You're interested if it contains anything but whitespace, so just remove all whitespace. `translate(...)` can get handy. The first parameter is what you're matching, the second string is what to match, and the third tells which characters to replace to; as it's empty, all matched characters will get deleted.

```
translate(., ' &#10;', '')
```

I could reproduce the issue with Perl's XPath and it was solved with this query:

```
/expectedVendorPaymentTransactions/orderEvents/node()[not(self::orderEvent) or self::text()[translate(., ' &#10;', '')!='']]
```

---

Update: Ruby does not seem to resolve the XML entities correctly, but you can use `\n` for newline instead:

```
translate(., ' \n', '')
```

Comment: Thanks Jens. That's not working for me in ruby unfortunately, it's still giving the same error message.

Comment: Is there any other whitespace involved? Tabs, carriage returns? I'm only filtering spaces and linefeeds that far.

Comment: No other whitespace is used. I've updated with a ruby file showing the issue, code and output are copied verbatim.

Comment: It seems Ruby is not resolving the entities correctly, but you can use `\n` for newline (which I would not regard worse comparing to XML entities...). I updated my answer. By the way, +1 for posting a great [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org)!

Comment: I think we're very close. Now it is returning a string ", " instead of an empty set. An empty array is still what's required up the call stack from this function. Calling split on the result is possible but not desirable. Is there a way to have this naturally return an empty array without split?

Comment: This seems like a bug when you combine the translate function with predicates. Either you've got to workaround and eleminate ", " strings from ruby or look for another solution. :(

Comment: Complete solution posted below. I'll give myself the answer as translate wasn't used. But a couple of +1s to Jens for the assistance.